# Kohana Route with digit parameter as directory name

Tags: kohana

I try to set the following Route with Kohana 3.2:

```
api/<version>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))(.<format>)
```

and want to put the controller in an directory inside the controller folder with the name of the `<version>` param. But how can I name the Class so that Kohana find my Controller?

e.g. :
I open the url `api/1.0/hello/say` and want to load the controller inside the folder `classes/controller/1.0/hello.php` but as the convention says I need to name the controller like Controller_1.0_Hello... But as far as I know, php doesn't allow numbers and points on classnames..

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map the route explicitly to any controller/method you want.   I wrote a tutorial that might help you out:  http://www.kineticklink.com/kohana-3-routing/

Basically, you can't have a period in a className, but you can have a number.

Answer (score 0):

`Routes are used to determine the controller and action for a requested URI`.

- `directory` is a folder;
- `controller is a file in`directory` folder;
- `action` is method of `controller` class (defined in file).

If you want to select specific file based on Route, your only way is to use `<controller>` instead of `<version>` like:

`api/<controller>(/<version>(/<action>(/<id>)))(.<format>)`;

You'll probably have to modify your URI format.